# Определение текста "/cmd param" в input'е

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Играл кто в SAMP (San Andreas Multiplayer), да и не только там есть такое понятие как команды, но как пример возьму именно эту игру.

В общем, в чате, при вводе текста типо `/cmd` или `/cmd param` - происходит какое-то действие, в зависимости от команды.

Хочу такое же реализовать в обычном input.

Нет, не вот таким вот вариантом `if($(input).val() == '/cmd')`..
Прям как там, т.е. если `input.val()` начинается с `/ (слеша)`, то определяем какая команда идёт после слеша и есть ли параметры.

Как такое можно реализовать? И как будет грамотнее?

---

**UPD** 12 минут спустя

Накатал вот такое вот:

```js
$('.s').on('click',function(){
 var inputVal = $('.c').val();
  if(inputVal[0]=='/') {
   inputVal = inputVal.slice(1);
   console.info('cmd? true');
    cmdInput(inputVal.split(' '));
  } else console.info('cmd? false');
});

function cmdInput(arr) {
 let cmd = arr[0], param = arr[1];
  console.info('\ncmd: '+cmd+'; \nparam: '+param+';');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="c" type="text" value="">
<input class="s" type="button" value="click">
```

Comment: Не забываем, что чатятся обычно в спешке, и велика вероятность ввода ошибочного параметра или двойного пробела-разделителя, например. Нужно предусмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я сделал.

В сниппете работают команды **`/hello`** и **`/stack`**.

```js
$('#search').bind('submit', function(){
let thisVar = $(this).find('input[name="q"]').val();
if(thisVar[0]=='/') {
 let str = thisVar.slice(1), cmd = str.split(' ', 1).toString(), param = str.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
  // cmd list
  if(cmd=='hello') alert('Hello World!');
  else if(cmd=='stack') {
    if(param=='overflow') alert('Приветствую на StackOverflow');
    else alert('Попробуйте /stack overflow');
  }
  // not cmd
  else alert('Такой команды не существует');
  $(this).find('input[name="q"]').val('');
 return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="search" action="/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```